# js code working in console but not in vs code

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

I'm a beginner, learning js. I was doing a course and the task provided was that to pop an alert when the button is clicked. Pretty Ez but everytime somehow the code just doesn't works even when I typed the code seeing the solution. Checked pretty much everything within my knowledge but couldn't figure it out. while trying the same thing in another computer, it worked without any problem :/[Here's the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGDTH.png)

Comment: Are you running this is the vsCode console? What environment are you running this in? To have a popup you will need a browser. So make an html file and import that script into it

Answer (score 0):

[Window.alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) is not native JS. It is a [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) method, meaning your browser source code implements it.

If you're running, say, a Node.js environment in VSCode's console, then it shouldn't really work. Node doesn't implement it either.

Comment: thanks a lot, actually I figured out that I was linking the js file in the header section rather than at the bottom of the body. Might sound weird but I tried out both the ways on another computer and the same thing happened. Well that was a pretty silly mistake XD

Answer (score 0):

I have made an example here on a code pen: https://codesandbox.io/s/buttontoalert-fs1kz3

What you need to do is create an index.html that is importing the script you want to run.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <button>Click Me</button>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in your index.js file which is the script you are importing in the html file the code is:

```
const button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", () => alert("I was clicked"));
```

These two file need to be in the same directory or you need to update the file path to where the js file is located relative to your html file.

The commands you are using a relative to a browser so need to be run with a browser or will not work.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I figured out that I was linking the js file in the header section rather than at the bottom of the body. Might sound weird but I tried out both the ways on another computer and the same thing happened. Well that was a pretty silly mistake XD